# How to create a post to LinkedIn

Tags: c#, linkedin-api

We are getting a HTTP error 400 Bad Request while creating the Post in linkedin using HTTP POST request.

Sample COde:

```
public static bool PostLinkedInNetworkUpdate(string accessToken, string title, string submittedUrl = "", string submittedImageUrl = "")
        {

            var requestUrl = String.Format(linkedinSharesEndPoint, accessToken);
            var message = new
            {
                comment = "Testing out the LinkedIn Share API with JSON",
                content = new Dictionary<string, string>
                { { "title", title },
                    { "submitted-url", submittedUrl },
                    {"submitted-image-url" , submittedImageUrl}
                },
                visibility = new
                {
                    code = "anyone"
                }
            };

            var requestJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(message);

            var client = new WebClient();
            var requestHeaders = new NameValueCollection
            {
                { "Content-Type", "application/json" },
                { "x-li-format", "json" },
                {"Host", "api.linkedin.com"}
            };
            client.Headers.Add(requestHeaders);
            var responseJson = client.UploadString(requestUrl, "POST", requestJson);
            var response = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(responseJson);
            return response.ContainsKey("updateKey");
        }
    }
```

We are getting an error message on the line:

```
 var responseJson = client.UploadString(requestUrl, "POST", requestJson);
```

as HTTP Error 400 Bad Request.

We have tested the code with GET Request which is working from my Dev server,However any of the POST requests are failing with this error message.

We have verified the REsponse headers with the request made from POSTMAN which is working.The response headers of POSTMAN are matching with the Bad Request response

Do we need to install the LinkedIn certificate in the Server?

Does anyone have any suggestions/comments?
Thanks in advance

Comment: most APIs if they send back a 400 give you a clue as to why, e.g. if there's a validation error there might be some JSON in the response body which tells you what the server thinks is wrong. And I think if there was an SSL error from a certificate missing you wouldn't even get this far. If this is running on a different server than your working request though it could be something like restrictions on the API side about which IP addresses can use the API

Comment: Also you've said you've verified the response headers are both the same in your C# and Postman versions, but what about the request headers, URL, and request body? There might be a difference there.

Comment: Catch exception and see if you can read response data from the exception properties and read Response.content stream . That can show you actual reason why it has failed. I have done the same using http web request and castes the exception to webexception, which contains Response property with content